# How use local images in react?

Tags: reactjs

From the database I get the paths to the images, they are located in the assets.
And I want to display them on the site along their path.

My project directory tree:

```
C:.
├───build
│   └───static
│       ├───css
│       ├───js
│       └───media
├───public
└───src
    ├───assets
    │   └───icon
    ├───componets
    │   └───UI
    └───pages
```

If I use "Import" (import quest1 from "../assets/image 4.png") everything works, but it's not what I need

Comment: So i can understand what constraints you're working under: is putting the images in the public directory an option or *must* they be imported?

Comment: First of all, if your images are stored in your app locally and not on a live server then you dont need to store the paths in your database, you sohuld create a function locally in your app that renders the img element based on the name of the image you want.

Comment: if you really want to do something like that then you need to store the images in public directory,  then store the url to that images in database ad they would work fine,

Comment: public directory is accessible from all the directories of the app